# Python (to C#) Method Conversion

Tags: c#, python, arrays

I am trying to reproduce this function in C#:

```
def sendData(self, eventCodes, data = None):
    if data:
        self.push('\x01'.join(map(str, [eventCodes] + data)) + "\x00")
    else:
        self.push(eventCodes + "\x00")
```

I believe that **eventCodes** is a string and **data** an array. I do not understand how map() works here though. I thought it iterates throughout an array executing a function for each item (in this case "str"). However, I don't see how ***[eventCodes] + data*** is an array.

I am interested in getting the result of this procedure `'\x01'.join(map(str, [eventCodes] + data)) + "\x00`" in C#.

Comment: `map(func, iterable)` is analagous to C#'s `iterable.Select(func)`. In python, `[array] + [array] == [array, array]`, which is just a list concatenation.

Comment: @Phoshi: using the word `array` to represent an item in an array there is plain confusing

Comment: @Eric: Correct, I think I changed direction with the example halfway through. Eugh. `[a] + [b] == [a, b]` is much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map(x, y)` would be akin to this C# code:

```
y.Select(item => x(item))
```

so this: `map(str, [eventCodes] + data)` would be akin to this:

```
([eventCodes] + data).Select(item => str(item))`
 ^-----------------^                 ^-^
```

The highlighted portions is not yet valid C# code. What is `str`, well, probably we can replace this with `ToString`:

```
([eventCodes] + data).Select(item => item.ToString())`
 ^-----------------^
```

`[eventCodes] + data` concatenates a list containing the single string `eventCodes` with the collection of strings in `data`, so we have this:

```
new[] { eventCodes }.Concat(data).Select(item => item.ToString())
```

Moving out one step, this:

```
`\x01`.join(...)
```

is in C#:

```
string.Join("\x01", ...)
```

so then we get this:

```
string.Join("\x01", new[] { eventCodes }.Concat(data)
    .Select(item => item.ToString()))
```

Final method:

```
public void sendData(string eventCodes, IEnumerable<string> data = null)
{
    if (data != null)
        push(string.Join("\x01", new[] { eventCodes }
            .Concat(data.Select(item => item.ToString()))) + "\x00");
    else
        push(eventCodes + "\x00");
}
```

Personally I would change the code as follows:

```
public void sendData(string eventCodes, IEnumerable<string> data = null)
{
    string element;
    if (data != null)
        element = string.Join("\x01", new[] { eventCodes }
            .Concat(data.Select(item => item.ToString())))
    else
        element = eventCodes;
    push(element + "\x00");
}
```

Comment: `data` is probably not an `IEnumerable<string>` given the python code had to `str`ify it

Comment: @DominicKexel Not sure I understand what you mean. "\x01" will add 1 codepoint to the output, with a value of 1. Should be the same as in Python.

Comment: @DominicKexel: In C# `'\x01'` is the char `0x01`, and `"\x01"` is a string containing that char. In python, there is no distinction between single and double quotes

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I know. Forgive me, I had no coffee yet so I misread the answer and talked nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

```
String.Join("\x01", (new[] {eventCodes}).Concat(data).Select(s => s.ToString()))
```

Piecewise:

- `str` => `x => x.ToString()`
- `[item]` => `new[] {item}`
- `arr1 + arr2` => [`arr1.Concat(arr2)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- `map(f, iterable)` => [`iterable.Select(f)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- `a.join(b)` => [`String.Join(a, b)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)